# How to get payoff function from probability?

Tags: game-theory

Okay, I am studying for my game theory midterm tomorrow and I am stumped at the practice final and I don't want to just look at the answer key. I would like some knowledge to substantiate my work.

I am given candidate 1's probability to win: s1/(s1+2)

and player 2's probability to win: s2/(s1+s2)

How do I get to the payoff function with what I have been given?

Comment: There is no one payoff function but an equivalence class. Often it will be given, but with only two outcomes and an obvious ordering (winning preffered to losing) it is not necessary. Payoff functions are maps from preferences to real numbers and any function which preserves the ordering of any weighted combination of preferences is equivalent, that is monotonic linear transformations in the context of decisions under uncertainty. When there are only two outcomes this is equivalent to payoff c when a player wins and b < c when player loses. Pick your favorite numbers b,c, b < c.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about gaming theory. Is payoff a single Bernoulli trial or during s1+s2 games? Anyway,

You need to consider the amount they bet. To compute average you need need a distribution, which means values coupled with probabilities, not the probabilities alone. If one sacrifices A dollars on a stake whereas another puts B on the stake in every trial, then, and taking prb theory notions, p=s1/(s1+s2) and q= 1-p,

We have two outcomes and distribution looks like, P(-A) = q, P(B) = p for the first and P(-B) = p, P(A) = q for the second. The average income of the first is $E_1 = p\cdot B-q\cdot A$ per game, therefore, and $E_2 = -E_1 = q \cdot A - p \cdot B$ for the second. You may look at this like you always bet A and, with probability p you take the jack pot of A+B: $E_1 = -A + p(A+B) = pB - A(1-P) = pB - Aq.$

If $A=B$ then $E_1 = A\cdot (p-q) = A\cdot {s1-s2\over s1+s2}$ and $E_2 = A\cdot {s2-s1\over s2+s1}.$

Multiply averages with (s1+s2) for that amount of games because average is the thing that is intended to serve as multiplier. You will get $E_1 = -A\cdot s2 + B \cdot s1$, the payoff of the first player. That is reasonable because you win $B \cdot s1$ in case opponent always looses, s2=0, and you loose $A\cdot s2$ when he always wins. The game is fair if $A\cdot s2 = B\cdot s1.$

How far am I from the point?